# RStudio cannot load web file, but R in terminal can; why?

Tags: r, github, ssl-certificate, rstudio

I'm running RStudio on Ubuntu 18.04. When I want to load [this data](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/airline-safety/airline-safety.csv) from GitHub

```
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/airline-safety/airline-safety.csv")
```

I get the following error message.

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection to 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/airline-safety/airline-safety.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/airline-safety/airline-safety.csv': status was 'Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)'
```

Yet when I run the very same command in the terminal it works without any error. How can that be? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That seems similar to [issue 1079](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1079#issuecomment-182390147) which includes:

> - Please restart R
> - then `install.packages(c("curl", "httr"))`
> - then try again.

If this is not enough, follow [swirldev/swirl/issue 475](https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/issues/475#issuecomment-251908790).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, neither solution worked. Both 'curl' and 'httr' were already installed. I tried loading the Github CSV with either of them loaded, or both, but to no avail. And running the commands from the swirldev link didn't fix it either.