# How to fix Error cannot open connection on Ubuntu machine?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, load

This might be a very trivial issue with R-related Ubuntu settings, but I'm pretty new to it and have no clue to solve this issue.

I'm trying to `load` a file from URL on a linux Ubuntu machine into R (R-Studio) with different strategies:

```
load(url("http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.rda"))
read.csv(url("http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.csv"))
readstata13::read.dta13("http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.dta")
data.table::fread("http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.csv")
```

but they all fail with similar error messages:

```
Error in load(url("http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.rda")) : 
  cannot open the connection to 'http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.rda'
In addition: Warning message:
In load(url("http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.rda")) :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.rda': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

that of `fread` is somewhat different:

```
trying URL 'http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.csv'
Error in download.file(input, tmpFile, method = method, mode = "wb", quiet = 
  !showProgress) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(input, tmpFile, method = method, mode = "wb", quiet = 
  !showProgress) :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.csv': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

This is what I got when I was mobile:

```
Error in load(url("http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.rda")) : 
  cannot open the connection to 'http://www.yaj.ch/data/test.rda'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> load
Execution halted
```

When I **Shift-click** on the link in the script, the data opens in the browser, so the connection **seems to be okay**.

On my Windows machine everything works fine. So I guessed the issue is related to Ubuntu, as if R has connection problems or wrong access rights. But I'm not sure, since strangely enough e.g. this one opens in Ubuntu:

```
load(url("http://www.rdatamining.com/data/graph.rdata?attredirects=0&d=1"))
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51924388/6574038) solution wasn't helpful to me, and Google won't tell me anything either.

Is there any help?

Comment: Visiting the site returns a `404`. Perhaps this is the reason?

Comment: This is just example code sorry. On the other windows machine it works fine.

Comment: @NelsonGon I've worked it out a little better now, with sample data.